# ExtJS 4 create View from Controller

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a Controller and I want to create a View in it:

```
var list = Ext.widget('installBaseList', params);
```

and this is the view:

```
Ext.define("FI.view.InstallBaseList", {
extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
require: 'FI.store.InstallBaseStore',
title: 'List',

alias: 'widget.installBaseList',
  //other config
});
```

I get `name is undefined`. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely your view is not loaded. Check dependencies and `requires`. If you're using non-minified version of your app - do you see file with view class loaded or not?

Comment: No, it is not loaded. I can not load it from the beginning because I have to get some parameters with ajax first. How should I proceed?

Comment: No. I mean file with view definition - did it get loaded by the browser?

Comment: No, I did not get loaded by the browser.

Comment: Make sure you list this view in the controller where you use it: `views: ['InstallBaseList']`

Comment: If I list the view like that in the controller, then it will get instantiated *before* I get the needed parameters for configuration. The view should only be instantiated when I want to, not when creating the controller.

Comment: It will not be instantiated at that time. it will be defined.

Answer (score 1):

Your code sort of works... Check this example http://jsfiddle.net/nscrob/EcX3Q/

The problem could be that you are trying to create the view in the init of the controler and the view is not yet defined. you could post the whole controler so we get a clearer view of your code

Comment: For some reason, the .js file containing the `FI.view.InstallBaseList` view doesn't get loaded in the browser. Could this be the reason? If so, how should I fix it?

Comment: yes this probably is the issue, Is your script added like :<script type="text/javascript" src="yourFile.js"></script>, preferably before the controller is added and after the store that the item is required.

Comment: I have tried this solution, but I still get the same error. Any other ideas?